# Is it legal to add Overlay maps to Apple MapKit framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, overlay, mapkit

Since iOS 6.0 uses Apple Map,I would like to add Google Map as Overlay by using TileOverlay.Is there any possibility that App store rejects the application ? Can I directly adapt Overlays to mapkit without significant change in my existing code? what about adding Annotations to Overlay Maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now Google Map release the new Google Maps SDK for iOS allows users to view and interact with a Google map in your iOS app. Let's check it out : [a link here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)! Cheers

Comment: Its not yet open for public.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using Googles new [maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro)?

Comment: Its not yet open for public.